# Alignment with RAID-6 (mdadm) + LUKS + XFS

Tags: raid, software-raid, luks, alignment, xfs

**What I want:**

- I have a 4x4TB RAID-6 array with mdadm.
- I want the storage to be encrypted and plan on using LUKS.
- I will most probably use XFS as filesystem.
- I will add more disks to the array as more space is required and money is available.

**How I thought to do it:**
Unless convinced otherwise, I was planning to simply create a LUKS container on the md array and place my filesystem inside the LUKS container.

I already took care of the alignment of the md array itself.

**My questions:**

1. How do I get the alignment of LUKS on top of the md array raight?
2. How do I get the alignment of XFS on top of LUKS right?
3. Does anything speak against my intended setup?

Comment: Normally, I would say to run LUKS between the physical storage device and the MD array. Is there any particular reason why you'd rather do PHY->MD->LUKS->XFS instead of PHY->LUKS->MD->XFS?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The [LUKS FAQ Section 2.2](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#2-setup) discourages this unless there are good reasons.